# LibGdx having multiple errors with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

For over a week I have been trying to learn LibGDX with Android Studio by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzBVTPaUUDg&t=320s). I am never able to build and run for the Desktop configuration. I have gone through many solutions over the internet but it lead to no solutions. Below I will show all the details about my project and files.

I am sorry for a long explanation but I had to show all the errors and details for a better analysis.

My versions of everything related is:

1. Android Studio version: 3.1.3
2. SDK tools: 26.1.1
3. Android platform version: API 28 revision 4
4. Gradle: 4.6
5. Android Plugin version: 3.1.0
6. Java: Java 8 update 171

This is the setup I chose on libgdx project setup:
[LibGdx Project Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH0rm.png)

This is the advance option (selected only Eclipse): [Advance option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsIg4.png)

I come across two warning dialog boxes, the first one was:

```
You have a more recent version of android build tools than the recommended.
Do you want to use your more recent version?
```

I selected NO, then it told me :

```
Using build tools: 27.0.3
```

The second one said:

```
You have a more recent Android API than the recommended.
Do you want to use your more recent version?
```

Again I selected NO, then it said:

```
Using API level: 27
```

After successfully completing the setup the message said:

```
Generating app in C:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\FlappyDemo
Executing 'C:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\FlappyDemo/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon eclipse afterEclipseImport'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018
:android:clean UP-TO-DATE
:core:clean UP-TO-DATE
:desktop:clean UP-TO-DATE
:eclipseProject
:eclipse
:android:eclipseClasspath
:android:eclipseJdt
:android:eclipseProject
:android:eclipse
:core:eclipseClasspath
:core:eclipseJdt
:core:eclipseProject
:core:eclipse
:desktop:eclipseClasspath
:desktop:eclipseJdt
:desktop:eclipseProject
:desktop:eclipse
:desktop:afterEclipseImport

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s
15 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 3 up-to-date
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> YourProject.ipr
```

I launched Android Studio and imported this project that I created using the LibGdx project setup.

The first error that I get when the project opens in Android Studio is:

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018
```

My main build.gradle file is this:

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "FlappyDemo"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties is this:

```
#Fri Jun 09 23:06:52 EDT 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip
```

My gradle.properties is:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms128m -Xmx1500m
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

So I change all the compile to implementation, my file becomes:

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "FlappyDemo"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Also, when I sync after updating the file, I was shown this message:

```
To take advantage of all the latest features (such as Instant Run), improvements and
security fixes, we strongly recommend that you update the Android Gradle plugin to
version 3.1.3 and Gradle to version 4.4.

You can learn more about this version of the plugin from the release notes.
```

I selected "remind me tommorow".
The sync was successful! I tested it by running it on my android phone and everything was fine, except for 1 warning:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
```

I was also shown an IDE error which was:

```
Editor of class com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl hasn't been released:
com.intellij.openapi.util.TraceableDisposable.ObjectNotDisposedException: See stack trace responsible for creation of unreleased object below 
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.<init>(EditorImpl.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorFactoryImpl.createEditor(EditorFactoryImpl.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorFactoryImpl.createViewer(EditorFactoryImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewUtil.setupConsoleEditor(ConsoleViewUtil.java:68)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewImpl.doCreateConsoleEditor(ConsoleViewImpl.java:903)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewImpl.lambda$createConsoleEditor$10(ConsoleViewImpl.java:880)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:47)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewImpl.createConsoleEditor(ConsoleViewImpl.java:879)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewImpl.initConsoleEditor(ConsoleViewImpl.java:452)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewImpl.getComponent(ConsoleViewImpl.java:431)
    at com.intellij.build.BuildTreeConsoleView$DetailsHandler.<init>(BuildTreeConsoleView.java:634)
    at com.intellij.build.BuildTreeConsoleView.<init>(BuildTreeConsoleView.java:222)
    at com.intellij.build.BuildView.onStartBuild(BuildView.java:128)
    at com.intellij.build.BuildView.lambda$onEvent$0(BuildView.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:653)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:666)
    at com.intellij.build.BuildView.onEvent(BuildView.java:86)
    at com.intellij.build.MultipleBuildsView.lambda$onEvent$2(MultipleBuildsView.java:163)
    at com.intellij.build.MultipleBuildsView.lambda$onEvent$3(MultipleBuildsView.java:288)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:924)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:217)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:589)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:409)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:318)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.run(CoreProgressManager.java:303)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Task.queue(Task.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(ExternalSystemUtil.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil.refreshProject(ExternalSystemUtil.java:381)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaGradleSync.sync(IdeaGradleSync.java:169)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.sync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:241)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.lambda$requestProjectSync$0(GradleSyncInvoker.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:153)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncInvoker.requestProjectSync(GradleSyncInvoker.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter.openOrImportProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:210)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter.openOrImportProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:110)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter.importProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidImportProjectAction.createImportWizard(AndroidImportProjectAction.java:201)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidImportProjectAction.selectFileAndCreateWizard(AndroidImportProjectAction.java:163)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidImportProjectAction.selectFileAndCreateWizard(AndroidImportProjectAction.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidImportProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidImportProjectAction.java:102)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink$1.linkSelected(ActionLink.java:66)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:156)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink.doClick(ActionLink.java:79)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel$MyMouseHandler.mouseReleased(LinkLabel.java:338)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:646)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I configure Desktop run from that same tutorial, here is the picture: [Desktop Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET9Z9.png)

After this is done, I run the program with Desktop selected, and get this error:

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip'.
```

This is where I am stuck, everythin works fine when run on android phone but when Desktop is selected this is the error I get. Now I followed many solutions from the internet but each of them further gave other errors, each solution gave a different error so I cannot put all the branches over here.

I am extremely in need for help at this point, thank you.

Comment: disable configuration on demand

Comment: org.gradle.configureondemand=false, it was by default put to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you're using `gdx-setup.jar` of [latest build](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/).

**Disable configuration on demand**

- Disable configuration on demand in your `gradle.properties` file as shown below:

  `org.gradle.configureondemand=false`
- To disable configuration on demand in the Android Studio settings, choose **File > Settings (Android Studio > Preferences** on Mac), select the **Compiler** category in the left pane, and clear the **Configure on demand** checkbox.

---

I'm currently using below version combination for LibGDX, recommend you to update some of them.

1. `buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"`
2. `Android Gradle Plugin version: 3.1.3`
3. `Gradle 4.6`
4. `Android API 28`
5. `Android Studio 3.1.3`

**EDIT**

You can also run your `desktop module` using `gradle` task

1. Using Terminal

   - Select Terminal using View `=>` Tool Windiow `=>` Terminal in Android Studio
   - use `gradlew desktop:run` on terminal (Windows)
2. Using Run/Debug configuration

   [image]

   - Add New configuration
   - Choose Gradle
   - **Gradle Project:** `=>` Select `:desktop` module of your project
   - **Tasks:** `=>` enter `run`
   - <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Apply</kbd>
   - Select your config and run

Comment: ok, so I followed youy solution and cleared the Configure on demand checkbox, now when I press run, I get the following message

"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\...
Error: Could not find or load main class com.saad.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: try to run again

Comment: hey, I dont know butI hit run again and it worked! Thanks a lot Aryan :)

Comment: my pleasure :)  you can also run using gradle configuration

Comment: can you elaborate on also run using gradle configuration? Sorry I am new to Android Studio and Gradle :)

Comment: oh thanks again man. I read other solutions on the internet where people said they could run from terminal and I couldn't understand that but now I know :D